# CallBack after push to GitHub

Tags: git, github, ftp, githooks

I want to push to an FTP server after I have pushed a commit to GitHub. Does Git have some kind of callback to call after a push went ok/

Can git hooks do this kind of job?

Comment: https://developer.github.com/webhooks/

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Git hook**

Unfortunately `git` does not have *post-push* hook (I hope I'm not wrong), but [*pre-push* hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push) (available since v1.8.2) should work for your particular scenario. FYI: list of `git` hooks can be obtained via [`man githooks`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

Official `git` repo has an [example of pre-push hook](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/templates/hooks--pre-push.sample), so you can use it as a template.

---

**Option 2: Github webhook**

Howerver, since you are using Github: you can use one of Github own features, [webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/), to achieve script execution after push, but on server side. In particular, you might be interested in [PushEvent](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent). Webhooks are a bit more complicated and requires you to host a web server and application to process requests ([example](https://gist.github.com/igrigorik/2017462)) from Github.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer. How can I do that?

Comment: Finished my answer. Pick your evil.